# IF Formula =IF(A6="a";1;0) strange behavior giving wrong result

Tags: excel, vba

A friend gave me a file with a strange result in it with the IF formula, it's an excel file with 2 sheet giving different result with the same formula.

I've also tried to compare those value with VBA but he give me the right answer, so `A5 != "a"`,i couldn't go further with the explanation because it's really something stupid, it's happening just with this file so i need to post it here:

http://www.filedropper.com/ifanomalie

It's a file with 5 rows of data, someone could explain me what's happening there?

Comment: Please post details here, not in a file which most people won't want to download.

Comment: Too bad, I just wanted to write an answer (I think the OP had no other choice than to post the file). Go to `File->Options`, choose `Advanced` and scroll down to the very end. Uncheck the (checked) option under "Lotus compability" for the affected sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an strange option set for your 1st sheet (`foglio1`). Generally, there is a surprising large amount of workbook and worksheet-specific settings in Excel.

Goto `File->Options`, choose `Advanced` and scroll down to the very end of the setting page. Under `Lotus compability Settings for`, choose `foglio1` and remove the checkmark on `Transition formula evaluation`.

When you select the other sheet (`foglio2`), you see that this is already unchecked (and so it is probably for all other sheets you will see until the end of your Excel life.)

The help page suggest that empty cells are treated differently, don't ask me about details or reasons.

[image: Setting that leads to the strange behaviour]

Comment: Thanks thomas, really helpful, never saw that checkbox in any of my files